# Is there any way to get Japanese Kanji suggestions from Hiragana? Android

Tags: java, android, kanji

Is there a library or any way I can implement this feature which takes hiragana character and returns kanji suggestions in android.

Let me explain my situation here,

I have a textview, where i set it's text to whatever character of hiragana the user selects from a customized keyboard which appears on the screen and then it appends the letters in the textview and it should suggest kanji symbols for it. so for example: if user selects ぐ then it should suggest 具,　愚,　組, etc., Kanjis.

This suggested kanji can be displayed on another textview.

I just want to know if this is possible to achieve and any idea how to do it.

This is my customized soft keyboard (part of it)
[image]

Comment: Are you using Kanji keyboard while typing this?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown No, I am using a soft keyboard that i created on my own. For your reference i have included an image of the part of the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To see Kanji Suggestion in the Japanese language you need to change the Japanese OS. Japanese OS have built-in 
Japanese keyboard.

```
Go there : Setting> System > Language and Input > Language > Add Japanese Language
```

If you don't want to change OS, then you can only change your keyboard by going

```
Setting> Keyboard > add Keyboard
```

If you want to custom library, You can use the static method UserDictionary.Words.addWord(....)
but you need to add permission

Normally Works: 
In your EditText need to allow InputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete" />
```

Comment: Sorry I am using TextView and I am using a customized soft keyboard.